# Which tracks on Formula D / Formule Dé has the greatest straight line?

Tags: formula-d

On Formula D/ Formule Dé, one's speed is determined by the dices you use. The Sixth dice, allows one player to move to a maximum of 30 spaces. This is the greatest dice available. Formula D/Formule Dé uses the same "tracks" as one can use any tracks of any given edition, it'd work freely.

I'm wondering which tracks has the longest straight line, in order to use this sixth dice.

Comment: All tracks allow it. The question of reasonableness will come down to a matter of opinion.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I think one can say that a straight line of 45 or more might be reasonable enough, I'm asking for feasability as in not dying instantly, which sadly isn't doable on Monaco nor Nevada. Do you fill it's still too broad? Any tips on how to rephrase it ?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's too broad / opinion-based. Rephrasing won't get around that, though. The longer the straights (and the straighter the curves around it), the more usable the 6th die. Other than that, there's not much area for discussion.

Comment: If it is too broad, instead of asking where the sixth dice can be used ask for the length of straight you want to have.  Even if as a matter of tactics someone thinks you are too cautious it is still answerable.

Comment: It also matters how much of a risk taker you are in games.

Comment: @Jontia edited, following your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually own Formula D so I am relying on the experts over at [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25749181#25749181). The information before relates to the current incarnation Formula D only, Formula De tracks from earlier releases of the game are not considered.

For the purpose of this question two points on the linked thread stand out...

> Baltimore/Buddh
>   I particularly like Buddh. The very long straight is the longest on any of the F1 tracks in the Formula D series (F De has several longer ones) and leads into a 1 stopper followed by an in between length to the 2 stopper.

And specifically mentioning 6th gear...

> Sebring/Chicago
>   - Sebring: A fun, challenging track, but in my experience, you can get runaway leaders on it if they hit the 1-stop corners just right. You can hit 6th gear easily.

Answer (score 1):

Estoril... by far !

But only if you race more than one lap.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the relevant datum (i.e., the length of the straightaway).